# How can I show a graphic component using programming (.ts files)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6.

A graphic component is an HTML template associated with logic inside a .ts file. If in another typescript file (associated with another component), i create an object that is actually a component, how can I graphically visualize that object in the template?

Code example:

Component 1 (.ts and .html):

```
class MyComponent1 {
 constructor(myString: string){}
}
--------------------------------
<p>My Component 1!</p>
```

Component 2 (.ts and .html):

```
class MyComponent2 {
 constructor(){
 }

 method() {
  let newComponent = new MyComponent1('a casual string');
  return newComponent;
 }
}
---------------------------------
{{method()}}
```

In the html of myComponent2 I would like to display the string 'My Component 1!' (that is the graphic part of the component), and not [object Object].
What is the way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain bit more, what do you mean by *graphic component*?

Comment: I refer to the html that refers to the component, that is its graphic part

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ***ngIf** directive for this implementation. you can list all possible component in the view (if possible) and show them when needed.

Or another approach can be using **elementRef**. You can use it and inject you component in same like you do it in JavaScript.

Another approach can be that you could use routing in this case. just simply out a  in the template and route your page according to your logic.

You can check dynamic components in angular documentation
[Dynamic Components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

I would suggest to use routing for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basics of how to use a component, you will be very quick up to speed with those concepts. You can have a quick look at [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

The idea is: when you define your components, you have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'componentXX',
  // ...
} export class XXXComponent ...
```

Then, from another component, you just use this in the HTML template: `<componentXX></componentXX>` and it will pull your component - given it's in the same scope, for now stay in the same module to learn about the basics.

Answer (score -1):

Simply Call in The object in .Html for example

`My Component 1!`

in template or in a Html File 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?